# how to use tags for APIGEN in netbeans?

Tags: php, netbeans-7, apigen

I am new to generating documentation for PHP code using open source scripts. I found that apigen is good and I have installed it for my project. Now I want to use it via net beans.

1. Main question is How I should comment my code they have not given any information about tags which I should use in my code .
2. I want to use only some directories to generate documentation because I am using   Laravel 4 framework so I would like to include only controller and models directory. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: For #1, type `/**` and click `Enter`.

Comment: Thanks for this help .I did some R & D and found answer of my questions.

Comment: For #2:

`apigen.phar generate --source path/to/controllers --source path/to/model --destination put/doc/here`